# How to use proper typescript types in mongodb find filter combined with a predefined schema?

Tags: typescript, mongodb, types

I am using native mongodb ([npmjs.com/mongodb](https://www.npmjs.com/package/mongodb)) driver for node.js.

I've a collection with following interface:

```js
interface Users {
  name: string;
  age: number;
  favoriteFood: string;
}
```

I've to query this collection like:

```js
const filter = { name: "lily" };
DB.collection("Users").find(filter);
```

Now, how will I define type of that `filter` variable?
I could use something like `Record<string, any>`. But that is vary broad.

```js
const filter: Record<string, any>
  = { nmae: "lily" } 
// see the miss typed name. Gives no errors.
// but I'd like to see a little type checking there.
```

So I tried

```js
const filter: Partial<Record<keyof Users, any>>
 = { name: "lily" } // this force me to use the same keys as in schema.
```

Now is there any way I can avoid the `any` type in the above code? So that it support all kinds of filters and operators like `$gt`, `$lt` etc.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Basically, you need to import `Filter` type from `mongodb` and then simply use it.

```
const filter: Filter<User> = {}
```

For example lets say you want to create a function that receives a filter object.

```
function find(filter: Filter<User> = {}) {
   return Db.collection<User>("users").find(filter).toArray();
}
```

Now you can call this function and have the auto complete suggestion. you can also use different operators such as `$in`.

Comment: Only seeing FilterQuery from Mongo and when I try this I get a type exception: 'No overload matches this call.'

Comment: If you are receiving that exception it probably means that library code base has changed and this answer is kind of deprecated. The answer was valid when I posted it though